# How to get the last url

Tags: php, curl, cookies

```
$cookiefile = 'cookie.txt';
$params = 'page=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&x=50&y=40';
$url='https://kproxy.com/doproxy.jsp';

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

/// at the end of the execution redirect me to this url
    ///

https://server4.kproxy.com/servlet/redirect.srv/sruj/sfywreskebutnn/p1/

what I want is to know how to keep the url in a data base or a txt file or save in variable sessions

Answer (score 1):

You can get the redirect url as follows:

```
$redirectUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Comment: I already tried that and it does not work  ::: is rediret to https://server4.kproxy.com/servlet/redirect.srv/sruj/sfywreskebutnn/p1/